# For Cell in Column Loop - Specify value for adjacent column cell based on location in loop

Tags: vba, excel

I've put together an excel VBA macro that loops through all used cells in column I, and checks if the value of the cell matches a word.

If the word is a match, I would like to set a random number, between 1-5, in the adjacent cell in column B.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim FLrange As Range
Dim AllStockLastRow As String
AllStockLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set FLrange = Range("I2:I" & AllStockLastRow)

For Each cell In FLrange
    If cell.Value = "Shure" Then
        Range("B2").Value = Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Else
    End If
Next cell
```

Obviously this code does not work, as it would just continue to reset the value of cell B2 over and over. I don't know how, but I would like the code to check the value of I2, and set the random number value for B2. Then check the value of I3, and set the random number for B3.... etc...

Sorry if the wording here is confusing. If I knew the terminology, I could probably find the answer via google, and not have to waste your time :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid `ActiveSheet` by fully qualifying your references:

```
Dim FLrange As Range
Dim AllStockLastRow As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'your sheet name

With ws 
    AllStockLastRow =.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set FLrange = .Range("I2:I" & AllStockLastRow)
End With

For Each cell In FLrange
    If cell.Value = "Shure" Then
        ws.Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value = WorksheetFunction.Randbetween(1,5)
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks @CallumDA. Just curious, is there a reason why I should avoid referencing ActiveSheet in this particular scenario?

Comment: @AlexRitter - `ActiveSheet` could be a `Chart` for one.

Comment: If you are working on a different sheet and run the macro from there (using Alt+F8, for example) then you will find yourself in some trouble.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @CallumDA Hey man, my script just finished running and im getting a "run-time error:13 Type mismatch" on the line "If cell.Value="Shure" Then. Any idea why this is?

Comment: The cells just contain text found from a vlookup. There are a few #N/A's where there was no match found. Would that cause it?

Comment: Sure would! `IFERROR` is a great worksheet formula to remove your errors

Comment: @CallumDA Alright I got it working without any errors. The only remaining issue is that the above script is clearing out all cell values in Column B where a "Shure" match is not found in column I. Is it possible to have the script keep the values in Column B if no match is found?

Comment: @AlexRitter, the code above will skip where it can't find "Shure" so shouldn't be overwriting anything. Have you changed the code at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136795/discussion-between-alex-ritter-and-callumda).

Answer (score 1):

you could use `AutoFilter()`

```
Sub main()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| reference your sheet name
        With .Range("I1:I" & .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)  '<--| reference its column I range from row 1 (header) down to the last not empty row
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Shure" '<--| filter column with "Shure"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, -7).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rand() + 1)" '<--| if any filtered cells other than headers then write the "random" formula in corresponding column B cells 
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter
            .Offset(, -7).Value = .Offset(, -7).Value '<--| get rid of formulas and leave only values in column B
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```